"Phone is starting..." won't disappear and apps don't mount (LineageOS)
Phone: Google Pixel 3a XL
OS: LineageOS 18.1 nightly bonito
Android version: 11
Problem:
When booting OS, screen message says "Phone is starting..." ["Smartphone wird gestartet..."], but nothing happens.
I can enter my password and I can still scroll from top to bottom in order to access the settings.
Questions:

Why do I see this message and how can I solve this issue? Do I need to flash a new lineage recovery image or OS version onto the phone? Would this mean a loss of data?
How can I retrieve my data (like photos)?

General infos:

phone is rooted
bootloader is unlocked
haven't used the phone for nearly 2 years, replaced display now and took following steps (don't know if those are related to the issue):


booted into recovery mode
enabled ADB
Flashed TWRP image: adb reboot bootloader, fastboot boot twrp.img
deleted data/system/locksettings.db (because I forgot my pattern password)
booted lineageos and with step 4 I was able to access the settings, create a new password and enable USB debugging
screen message says "Phone is starting..."

My primary goal is to get my personal data (like photos off the phone), after that I'd do a factory reset..
Many thanks in advance for your answers/help!

What you did already invalidates any further attempt to access your previous data.

@ChanganAuto which of my steps taken exactly prevents me from accessing my data?

Deleting locksettings.db. If only it were so easy to bypass encryption, anyone can do what you did. Yes, in Linux desktop you can force a password change without knowing the previous, it doesn't mean you can then access the personal files of the previous user just like that.

@ChanganAuto does that mean that by deleting this db file I erased my chance of accessing my data - even if I happen to remember the original password?

you deleted the credentials for your original user. You havge now a new user / new password

@ChanganAuto Thank you for your explanations - that's horrible news, memories gone forever - cannot believe how dumb I was not to save a copy of the deleted db file.. if you put your comments into an answer then I can mark it as excepted answer, in case you care about it
